# Calculus 1, True / False question

Tags: calculus

The statement is:
If the function $f$ continuous in $[a,b]$. so there is a point $a<c<b$ such as:
$f(c) = f(a) + (f(b) - f(a)) / 3$.

Now there is 3 answers:

1.This statement is False by given an example of function which there is no point such as..

2.This statement is True and can be proven by Weierstrass (Extreme value theorem).

3.This statement is True and can be proven by intermediate value theorem.

So, I'm pretty sure this statement is true but I cant find how to prove it.
I though first of the intermediate value theorem because it's look kind of similar but nothing comes to my head.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The answer is 3).

Comment: I'd rather say it follows from the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: The answer should be it's true by the intermediate value theorem. Is that what Weierstrass refers to?

Comment: Yes that's what I though, can any of you guys can show me how I can use the intermediate value theorem to prove it?

Comment: @Armeet: That is very sloppily written. The theorem does not follow, and writing it as $f(c)$ begs the question.

Comment: ok. So how about let $m=min\{f(a),f(b)\}$. let $n=max\{f(a),f(b)\}$. let y = $f(a)+(f(b)−f(a))/3$. Show that $m \le y \le n$. Then does the result follow from the intermediate value theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $d =  f(a) + \frac {f(b)-f(a)}3 $

If you can prove that $\min (f(a), f(b)) \le d \le \max (f(a),f(b))$ then the result follows directly from the intermediate value theorem. $f$ is continuous, and $d\in [\min(f(a),f(b)), \max(f(a), f(b))]$ so there exists a $c\in [a,b]$ where $f(c) = d =f(a) + \frac {f(b)-f(a)}3$

So let's prove  $\min (f(a), f(b)) \le f(a) + \frac {f(b)-f(a)}3 \le \max (f(a),f(b))$.

$f(a) + \frac {f(b) -f(a)}3 = \frac 23 f(a) + \frac 13 f(b)$ and so

$$\frac 23 \min(f(a), f(b)+\frac 13\min(f(a),f(b)) \le  \\\frac 23 f(a) + \frac 13 f(b)\le \\\frac 23 \max(f(a), f(b)+\frac 13\max(f(a),f(b))$$ and so

$\min(f(a), f(b)) \le \frac 23 f(a) + \frac 13 f(b)\le  \max (f(a),f(b))$.

Comment: Thanks! really appricate it.

Answer (score 0):

The "intemediate value theorem" says that if f is continuous on [a, b] and F lies between f(a) and f(b) then there exist c, between a and b, such that f(c)= F.

To apply that here, show that f(a)+ (f(b)- f(a))/3 lies between a and b. Of course, f(a)+ (f(b)- f(a))/3= (2/3)f(a)+ (1/3)f(b).

Comment: "To apply that here, show that f(a)+ (f(b)- f(a))/3 lies between a and b"  I think you mean "lies between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.